# Stacked in a loop creating friendship with tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, friend-function, twitter-follow

So Im trying to follow users, but the problem is that it works on every user except the last one that I have in my to_follow.txt:

```
Chile_Temblores
Aguas_Antof
costaneranorte_
onemichile
Edelaysen
Chilquinta600
CGE_Clientes
Frontel_
EnelClientesCL
javi1597
```

The code that Im using is the following:

```
def createFriends(api):
    accounts = open("to_follow.txt", "r")
    friends = api.friends_ids()
    print("friends:", friends)
    follow = accounts().split('\n')
    print (follow)

    for account in follow:
        if account not in follow:
          api.destroy_friendship(account)
    for account in follow:
        if account not in friends:
          print("account: ", account)
          fuentes.append(account)
          api.create_friendship(account)
          print("friendship created")
     print(fuentes)

    accounts.close()
```

So when I print what is happening, it stops in javi1597 and it does not exit de execution, Where is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not exit the execution"?

Comment: I mean that it follows all the accounts before javi1597 and when it gets to this one it stays like "executing" in the api.createfriendship

Comment: Could something else be keeping the function from a completion? For instance, one of `api` methods? If `createFriends` does not print "friendship created" for javi1597 then it is busy in `api`.

Comment: Thats what is happening but I dont get why, cause it works for all the other users

Comment: Well, you need to look into `api` code for a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have used the variable "accounts" instead of using the file name "to_follow" as a method:

```
def createFriends(api):
    accounts = open("to_follow.txt", "r")
    friends = api.friends_ids()
    print("friends:", friends)
    print(accounts)

    for account in accounts:
        if account not in friends:
          print("account: ", account)
          fuentes.append(account)
          api.create_friendship(account)
          print("friendship created")
    print(fuentes)

    accounts.close()
```

Else I don't understand where the function to_follow() is coming from and why you don't use the created variable "accounts".

Edit: I refactored your code. You don't have to split the file but can directly iterate over the rows with "for in".

Edit 2: When you trying to add the last element "javi1597" it could be possible, that it also contains the "end of file" and it should be removed before you pass it into your API. Only an idea.

Comment: to_follow is a txt that contains all the users i want to follow, and then i split them when they have \n

Comment: Yes "to_follow.txt" is your file, but I was talking about your "to_follow()" method/function that you try to split. Because your txt file is loaded into the variable "accounts" and not "to_follow".

Comment: Im sorry I got that wrong, I have in my code as you say it is

Comment: What do you mean by it should be removd, what do you suggest me to do, Im really new with this

Comment: Replace "fuentes.append(account)" with "fuentes.append(strip(account))". It should remove the white space and possible end-of-file (EOF).